# How to hide next and prev btn in carousel using vue 2 / nuxt js?

Tags: vuejs2, nuxt.js

I have created a multi items carousel in which i slide one item at a time.
Initially i want to hide prev btn , but when clicked on next btn and one or more item is moved/slide to left in want the prev btn to be visible and when i am at end of the caorusel items i want to hide next button

template

```html
<div class="main-container">
    <div class="carousel-container position-relative" ref="container">
      <div class="carousel-inner overflow-hidden">
        <div class="carousel-track" >
          <nuxt-link to="" class="card-container" v-for="(index, i) in 9" :key="i">
            <div class="card"></div>
          </nuxt-link>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="btns-container">
        <button class="prevBtn" @click="prev" >
          prev
        </button>
        <button class="nextBtn" @click="next" >
          next
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

script

```js
methods: {
    next() {
      const track = document.querySelector('.carousel-track')
      const item = document.querySelector('.card-container')
      track.scrollLeft += item.clientWidth
    },

    prev() {
      const track = document.querySelector('.carousel-track')
      const item = document.querySelector('.card-container')
      track.scrollLeft -= item.clientWidth
    },
  }
```

styles

```css
.carousel-track{
    display: flex;
    overflow: auto;
    scroll-snap-type: x mandatory;
    scroll-behavior: smooth;
    scrollbar-width: none;
  }

  .carousel-track::-webkit-scrollbar {
    display: none;
  }

  .card-container{
    flex-shrink: 0;
    scroll-snap-align: start;
  }

  .btns-container button{
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
  }

  .prevBtn{
    left: -1rem;
    
  }

  .nextBtn{
    right: -1rem;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should not use querySelectors but rather state since you're working with Vue.
Sorry, I didn't had a carousel example so I did something a bit different.

```html
<template>
  <div class="main-container">
    <div ref="container" class="carousel-container position-relative">
      <div class="carousel-inner overflow-hidden">
        <div class="carousel-track">
          <nuxt-link
            v-for="(city, index) in cities"
            :key="city.id"
            to=""
            class="card-container"
          >
            <div
              class="card"
              :class="index === currentCityIndex && 'active-city'"
            >
              {{ city.name }}
            </div>
          </nuxt-link>
        </div>
      </div>

      <br />
      <p>Current city index: {{ currentCityIndex }}</p>
      <div class="btns-container">
        <button v-show="currentCityIndex !== 0" class="prevBtn" @click="prev">
          prev
        </button>
        <button
          v-show="currentCityIndex !== cities.length - 1"
          class="nextBtn"
          @click="next"
        >
          next
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      currentCityIndex: 0,
      cities: [
        { name: 'New york', id: '1' },
        { name: 'Los Angeles', id: '2' },
        { name: 'Chicago', id: '3' },
        { name: 'Houston', id: '4' },
        { name: 'Philadelphia', id: '5' },
        { name: 'Phoenix', id: '6' },
        { name: 'San Antonio', id: '7' },
        { name: 'San Diego', id: '8' },
        { name: 'Dallas', id: '9' },
        { name: 'San Jose', id: '10' },
      ],
    }
  },
  methods: {
    next() {
      this.currentCityIndex++
    },
    prev() {
      this.currentCityIndex--
    },
  },
}
</script>

<style scoped>
.active-city {
  border: 2px solid red;
}
</style>
```

The idea is mainly to do a check on the button with `v-show="currentCityIndex !== 0"` and display it depending on the current index you're on. You can of course also use [visibility](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/visibility) or any kind of cool CSS approach to avoid any shift regarding the location of the buttons.

`v-show="currentCityIndex !== cities.length - 1"` is checking if we are on the last element of your collection.

Answer (score 0):

This is a basic carrousel I sometimes use and modify if I need it. It is originally an infinite carrousel but I added that function you are looking for.

You can copy the code and check how it works and sure I can be improve a lot. But so far it works.

#### Template

```
<template>
    <div class="main-container">
        <div class="carrousel-container">
            <span ref="nextArrow" @click="nextSlide" class="slider-btn next">
                <svg
                    width="25"
                    height="43"
                    viewBox="0 0 25 43"
                    fill="none"
                    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
                >
                    <path
                        d="M23.5858 20.0623L4.39859 0.875151C3.13866 -0.384778 0.984375 0.507553 0.984375 2.28936V40.6638C0.984375 42.4456 3.13866 43.3379 4.39859 42.078L23.5858 22.8908C24.3668 22.1097 24.3668 20.8434 23.5858 20.0623Z"
                    />
                </svg>
            </span>
            <span ref="prevArrow" @click="prevSlide" class="slider-btn prev">
                <svg
                    width="25"
                    height="43"
                    viewBox="0 0 25 43"
                    fill="none"
                    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
                >
                    <path
                        d="M1.41421 20.0623L20.6014 0.875151C21.8613 -0.384778 24.0156 0.507553 24.0156 2.28936V40.6638C24.0156 42.4456 21.8613 43.3379 20.6014 42.078L1.41421 22.8908C0.633165 22.1097 0.633165 20.8434 1.41421 20.0623Z"
                    />
                </svg>
            </span>

            <!-- carousel -->
            <div
                :id="activeSlideIndex"
                v-if="showSlides"
                class="carousel-container"
            >
                <div
                    class="slide"
                    ref="slide"
                    v-for="(slide, idx) in slides"
                    :class="slide.position"
                    :key="slide.id"
                >
                    {{ idx }}
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- carousel -->
        </div>
    </div>
</template>
```

#### Script and Styles

```
<script>
export default {
    props: {
        slides: {
            type: Array,
            default: () => [
                { id: 1, name: "sliderOne" },
                { id: 2, name: "slider Two" },
                { id: 3, name: "slider Three" },
            ],
        },
    },
    mounted() {
        this.orderSlides(this.slides, this.activeSlideIndex);
    },
    data() {
        return {
            activeSlideIndex: 0,
            showSlides: false,
        };
    },
    methods: {
        nextSlide() {
            ++this.activeSlideIndex;
            this.displayOrder(this.activeSlideIndex);
        },
        prevSlide() {
            --this.activeSlideIndex;
            this.displayOrder();
        },
        displayOrder() {
            if (this.activeSlideIndex === this.slides.length) {
                console.log(this.activeSlideIndex);
                this.activeSlideIndex = 0;
            } else if (this.activeSlideIndex < 0) {
                this.activeSlideIndex = this.slides.length - 1;
            }

            this.orderSlides(this.slides, this.activeSlideIndex);
        },
        orderSlides(array, activeIndex) {
            array.forEach((element, idx) => {
                element.position = "nextSlide";
                if (idx === activeIndex) {
                    element.position = "activeSlide";
                } else if (
                    idx === activeIndex - 1 ||
                    (activeIndex === 0 && idx === array.length - 1)
                ) {
                    element.position = "lastSlide";
                }
            });
            if (!this.showSlides) {
                this.showSlides = true;
            }

            // toggle arrows
            if (activeIndex === array.length - 1) {
                this.$refs.nextArrow.style.display = "none";
            } else if (activeIndex === 0) {
                this.$refs.prevArrow.style.display = "none";
            } else {
                this.$refs.nextArrow.style.display = "block";
                this.$refs.prevArrow.style.display = "block";
            }
        },
    },
};
</script>


    <style scoped>
.main-container {
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100%;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
    overflow: hidden;
    display: grid;
    place-content: center;
}
.carrousel-container {
    width: 769px;
    height: 631px;
    position: relative;
    padding-top: 37px;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
}
.slider-btn {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
}
.slider-btn svg {
    fill: red;
}
.next {
    right: 25px;
}

.prev {
    left: 25px;
}

.carousel-container {
    width: 600px;
    height: 631px;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    display: flex;
    background: white;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    flex-direction: column;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.slide {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    opacity: 0;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    font-size: 2rem;
    transition: 0.3s all linear;
    background: var(--primary-light);
    border-radius: var(--border-radius-1);
}
.slide.activeSlide {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: translateX(0);
}
.slide.lastSlide {
    transform: translateX(-100%);
}
.slide.nextSlide {
    transform: translate(100%);
}
img {
    width: 100%;
}
</style>
```

Comment: You should rather recommend some state-based UI changes here since OP is using Vue.js IMO.